# Everytime I save to a file, data within the structure is overwritten/edited - C programming

Tags: save, structure, fopen

So when I use this 'save' function, it seems to change the data within my structure, to random numbers and icons. If i don't save the file then the integrity of the data within the structure keeps true to the original input.

I'm not sure where the error could be or how to even start to fixing this, thanks for any help.

here is my structure;

```
struct packet{ // declare structure for packet creation
        int source;
        int destination;
        int type;
        int port;
        char data[51];
    };
```

here is the function;

```
//Save the records to a file: follows the same principle as list but uses a file handle (pointer to a file)
//and fprintf to write to the file
void save(int rCount, struct packet *records){
      FILE *recordFile;                 //file handle
      char fileName[30] = { '\0'};      //string to store the file name
      int i;

      puts("Enter a filename to save the records :");   //ask the user for the filename
      scanf("%s", fileName);                            //store the filename: data input should be checked
                                                        //here in your program

      //try and open the file for writing and react accordingly if there is a problem
      if((recordFile = fopen(fileName,"w"))==NULL){
          printf("Couldn't open the file: %s\n",fileName);
          exit(1);
      }
      else{ //the file opened so print the records array of packet to it
          for(i=0;i<rCount;i++){
                fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%s\n",records[i].source,
                                                              records[i].destination,
                                                              records[i].type,
                                                              records[i].port,
                                                              records[i].data);
                }
                fclose(recordFile);   //close the file

          }


}
```

Comment: you are writing the memory address of records[i].(item)

Answer (score 2):

How do you know the structure data is corrupted?  Based on your code, I can see your output to file will be wrong based on this line:

```
fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%s\n",&records[i].source,
                                                          &records[i].destination,
                                                          &records[i].type,
                                                          &records[i].port,
                                                          &records[i].data);
```

Your pointer referencing is off.  Assuming the rest of your program is correct, simply remove the leading &s and I'm guessing this solves most if not all of your problem:

```
fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%s\n",records[i].source,
                                                          records[i].destination,
                                                          records[i].type,
                                                          records[i].port,
                                                          records[i].data);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry that was an error in my coding when I've been checking to see if it helps with the error. After taking the "&'s" out, it still goes over the data entered in the structure. 
Thanks

Comment: You don't assign anything to the records array in the save function.  If the records array is actually changing, I suspect the problem is elsewhere.  Just a hint, pointer mistakes can cause all kinds of hard to track down problems.  Meanwhile, try posting more code, including the code that creates and fills the records array, as well as the code that calls the save function.